# Why do I get Error: Missing one or more required components of PHP that MediaWiki needs (mbstring)?

Tags: php, mediawiki, mbstring

I have mediawiki on my local machine.  I have php and php-mbstring installed.  When I run phpinfo(), mbstring shows up.  I have checked that I have mbstring.ini and mbstring.so, and they are on my machine.

When I run `php maintenance/update.php` I get this error:

```
Error: Missing one or more required components of PHP.
You are missing a required extension to PHP that MediaWiki needs.
Please install:
 * mbstring <https://www.php.net/mbstring>
```

mbstring is installed and enabled, so I am not sure what to do here.

---

Versions:

- php CLI: 7.4.5
- php : 7.3.19-1
- MediaWiki: 1.34.1

Comment: That error message is triggered by a `function_exists( 'mb_substr' )` check. Probably a web server configuration issue, e.g. it's enabled for the web but not CLI.

Comment: Thank you @Tgr.  This little issue had me very confused and frustrated. I do not know very much about web server configuration, so I do not know how to fix that.

For anyone who with the same issue who needs to update, I was able to update from mediawiki by going to `/mw-config`.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said in the comments, you may have `mbstring` enabled only for your PHP backend, like `php-fpm`.

To make sure that `mbstring` is enabled for `php-cli`, type `php -i | grep 'mbstring'` in your console. If there is no output, `php-cli` has no access to `mbstring`. Alternatively, you can use `phpquery -v 7.4 -s cli -m mbstring`.

The best way to enable PHP extensions everywhere is to use `sudo phpenmod mbstring`. You can also check the existence and contents of `/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini` (`extension=mbstring.so`).

If you have build PHP from source for debug, then the location of `.ini` files may be different.