# Missing required extensions to PHP for MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

In the directory where PHP is installed I have created a php.ini file and verified that configuration files are coming from the php.ini. Extensions that are missing are enabled like so:

```
extension=mbstring
extension=fileinfo
extension=intl
```

*php_mbstring.dll*, *php_fileinfo.dll* and *php_intl.dll* files are present in the *ext* directory. How can I troubleshot this problem further?
I have looked for answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63626586/why-do-i-get-error-missing-one-or-more-required-components-of-php-that-mediawik) and [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Ujkkhbwt651o8xpk).

**edit**

I have also edited *php.ini-development* and *php.ini-production* uncommenting the relevant extensions from above. The *mbstring.dll* was downloaded from [here](https://www.dll-files.com/php_mbstring.dll.html). I unzipped the *dll* to *php-directory/ext*

Comment: *"I have created a php.ini"* You should edit the existing one.

Comment: Yes, you need to edit the php.ini that PHP is actually using. Beware there can be more than one in your install - for web and command-line, plus maybe an example one. And did you actually also _install_ those extensions, not just enable them in config? The process for making PHP extensions work [is not exactly a mystery](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+install+and+enable+php+extensions)

Comment: I have edited my question with your suggestions @ADyson. Is there any other configuration files I missed?

Comment: Don't just haphazardly / randomly change all the ini files you happen to find. Find the one which is actually used for the environment you're working in, and change that one. (If it's for the web PHP, then if nothing else, running `phpinfo();` in a php page will tell you which ini file it's reading from.) Then make sure the extension files are actually installed in the correct location, and are the correct ones for your operating system. Then restart your webserver.

Comment: I have verified by running ```phpinfo();``` that my configuration file comes from *php-8.3.2/phpini*  file

Comment: Ok. And what operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 11.

Comment: Thanks. So have you now done all the steps I described above? There is also already a full guide in the PHP manual here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

Comment: There are also many other guides such as https://sebhastian.com/mbstring-missing-php/#install-mbstring-for-windows . N.B. Make sure you insert the name of the extension correctly into php.ini - it looks like you may have the wrong name for mbstring, it should likely be mb_string

Comment: And for security, reliability, and valid choice of versions please only download missing DLLs from the official site at https://windows.php.net/download or https://pecl.php.net/ whenever possible, not from random other places online

Comment: Please check that the .dll files you've downloaded are compatible with your version of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I encountered was a bit special. I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63639881/php-intl-extension-not-loading-after-enabling-it). Apparently there are 4 files *icu*****.*dll* in the PHP executable directory. After copying those to the *bin* directory of Apache Server, the extensions worked.